# How do I segment a single jpeg into multiple images?

Tags: printing

I can only print up to a c plot size photo. I want to segment a single jpeg image to make a much bigger (composite), image. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do a tiled print. There are ways to do it yourself in software such as photoshop and/or gimp. I have never tried doing it that way. There are also websites that do a pretty good job for you. I think those are more limited by file size so if you are working with a large file you will probably end up doing it yourself. Checkout http://www.blockposters.com/ or http://rasterbator.net/ and see if they do what you want. Also, checkout a fellow stackexchange post I found that I think covers how you would do it yourself in photoshop. Which involves using slices https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/how-to-cut-a-large-photo-into-a-grid-of-smaller-photos-automatically-in-photosho
Also, if you do not have photoshop or gimp you might try a tool specifically designed to do this called PosteRazor.

Answer (score 0):

Irfanview can probably help you.
Photoshop can do it too.

Can you show a link to a product like the one you want to make?